# MSIX AppInstaller updates not working on Windows version 20H2 reliably

Tags: wpf, windows, uwp, appx, msix

I created an WPF application that I am attempting to install on different versions of windows and a variety of machines. On the machine that I have been building the application everything has been fine. I built the .appinstaller file using Pipelines and it installs on my Windows 10 Home - 21H1 build of windows. But I need it to work on my other machine which is a Windows 10 Pro - 20H2 machine. The issue...

When I install the application on 20H2 machine sometimes it will install and launch just fine but other times when I am attempting to update it or install it after I have uninstalled it, the app installer will launch and get stuck in a variety of spots. Sometimes it gets hung up on "Hang on while we get your app's information" and other times it will get to the install or update screen and you can press the update/install but but then it just sits there and says "Getting the system ready for install".

Taking a look at event viewer, sometimes the Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.16_12986.0. throws an error saying "Application Hang" with the hang type being Cross-process. I don't know if this is a specific issue to 20H2 version of windows or something different. I have looked in AppXDeploymentServer/Operational and there are a few errors related to the AppInstaller like....
Appinstaller operation failed with error code 0x80D01001. Detail: Unknown Error.
*Appinstaller operation failed with error code 0x80190192. Detail: Forbidden (403)

Comment: It might be possible to to atleast partially decrypt this message at this [Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/upgrade-error-codes).